Application of Wald's equation to bound a sum
I'm wondering if Wald's equality can be modified and applied as an inequality, given that we have $\forall i\; \mathbb{E}[X_i]\leq c$ with $c$ being a constant.
More specifically, given that $N$ and $X_i$ are not independent, and $N$ is a stopping time, can we say that:
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_i\right]\leq c\cdot\mathbb{E}[N]$$
It's also true that $1\leq N \leq b$ where b is a constant.

Short answer: yes. Simply apply Wald's equation to the sequence $Y_i = X_i + c - \mathbf{E}[X_i]$.
But it's also instructive to review the proof of Wald's equation and observe that it would directly yield the inequality.
The key precondition that Wald's equation needs is that for all $i$,
$$
   \mathbf{E}[X_i \, \mathbf{1}(N \geq i)] = \mathbf{E}[X_i] \, \mathbf{P}[N \geq i]. \qquad (*)
$$
From this, under the additional assumption that for all $i$, Wald's equation follows from linearity of expectation (or Fubini/Tonelli if $N$ has unbounded support), applying $(*)$, plugging in $\mathbf{E}[X_i] = c$, and using the tail sum formula $\mathbf{E}[N] = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \mathbf{P}[N \geq i]$.
If instead of an equality you use $\mathbf{E}[X_i] \leq c$, then exactly the same steps yield an inequality.
(Clarification about the precondition to Wald's equation: $(*)$ to hold, it suffices that $X_i$ and the event $N \geq i$ be independent, for which it in turn suffices that $N$ be a stopping time with respect to a mutually independent $X_i$ sequence.)

Thank you! I may need to carefully verify my claim that N is a stopping time, but your answer has been very helpful.
